# Hub Site Settings Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

so recently I've set a site to be a site hub in my tenant. I wanted to add a logo to the hub navigation bar, but when I click the gear icon on the top right it doesn't show hub site settings. Is there anyway to make the hub site settings show? Thanks before!

Comment: Are you a site collection administrator?

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes I am an administrator for the hub site collection and the associated sites.

Comment: Site collection administrator is a different role I believe. You can confirm by going to site permissions and selecting site collection administrators from the ribbon (this option will not be available if you are not a site collection administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the admin center and ensure the site has been registered as a hub site like the screenshot below? Hub site settings shall be enabled in no time. And you shall have the hub site top navigation.

[image]

Comment: The site is registered as a hub site, as the hub site top navigation is shown and is editable. The only thing missing is hub site settings, and I need that to show a logo of my company on the hub site top navbar. As for the admin side of things, unfortunately I am not a tenant admin so that I can't see the sites page in the admin center (I requested my site to be set as a hub site to my tenant admin)

Answer (score 0):

If the site admin permissions aren't set correctly initially on the Hub Site, it will take 15 minutes or so for the Hub permission settings to become available for use by the admin after the admin has been added correctly to the hub - at least in my experience.

Can be confusing due to this delay.